# Filter result with two where clauses in it

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to filter property with two type multi checkbox :

> 1 - Option
>
> 2 - Type

Here is my tables for this type:

**propety_type**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `property_type` (
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `PropertyNumber` int(4) NOT NULL,
    `TypeNumber` int(50) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=25 ;

INSERT INTO `property_type` (`ID`, `PropertyNumber`, `TypeNumber`) VALUES
(13, 53, 1),
(14, 53, 2),
(15, 53, 3),
(16, 54, 3),
(17, 54, 5),
(18, 55, 6),
(19, 55, 8),
(20, 56, 3),
(21, 56, 2),
(22, 56, 1),
(23, 54, 1),
(24, 55, 1);
```

**property_option**:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `property_option` (
   `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `PropertyNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `OptionNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=53 ;


INSERT INTO `property_option` (`ID`, `PropertyNumber`, `OptionNumber`) VALUES
(35, 53, 1),
(36, 53, 2),
(37, 53, 3),
(39, 54, 3),
(40, 54, 5),
(41, 55, 6),
(42, 55, 8),
(43, 56, 2),
(45, 56, 1),
(46, 56, 3),
(47, 56, 8),
(48, 53, 9),
(49, 53, 4),
(50, 55, 1),
(51, 54, 2),
(52, 54, 1);
```

My query :

```
SELECT property.PropertyNumber 
FROM property
INNER JOIN property_option ON property.PropertyNumber = property_option.PropertyNumber 
WHERE property_option.OptionNumber IN (1,3 ) 
GROUP BY property.PropertyNumber 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT property_option.ID) =2 
INNER JOIN property_type ON property.PropertyNumber = property_type.PropertyNumber 
WHERE property_type.TypeNumber IN (1,2 ) 
GROUP BY property.PropertyNumber 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT property_type.ID) =2
```

But when i test this in phpmyadmin, i get this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN property_option ON property.PropertyNumber = property_option.Property' at line 9

Comment: MySQL has a syntax to which one must adhere

Comment: You don't get to have two WHERE clauses unless you make at least one of them a nested select. You could consider making them nested selects or even views instead.

Comment: SELECT SQL has an sequence you should use it as  `SELECT * FROM table JOIN table [MORE JOINS...] WHERE [...] GROUP BY [....] HAVING [....]`

Comment: for property_option.OptionNumber IN (1,8 ) ,peropertyNumber result is:56,55 and property_type.TypeNumber IN (1,3 ) ,peropertyNumber result is:53,54,56 and in end it must get :56 ,How i change query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make sure the rows returned fulfills the requirement of having both specified options as well as both specified types then you can use the query below.

```
SELECT p.PropertyNumber
FROM property p
JOIN property_option  USING (PropertyNumber)
JOIN property_type    USING (PropertyNumber)
WHERE OptionNumber IN (1,8) 
  AND TypeNumber   IN (1,2) 
GROUP BY p.PropertyNumber 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT OptionNumber) = 2 
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT TypeNumber)   = 2;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b54f/2)